# Cannot see local class variables while debugging DLL in Visual Studio..?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, com, office-addins

I'm trying to debug a DLL that I've written in VB.Net. When the external program starts, it loads the DLL and everything runs fine...but I cannot see the class variables in the Locals pane. They show up blank as shown below.

Also, some lines of code generate the error "There is no source code available for the current location", but I think I understand why. Whenever it tries to step into class members of any of the Microsoft DLLs, it would of course have no information for those. But any lines which deal only in code that I've written, it works fine.

[image]

This is a COM DLL AddIn for Microsoft Access 2007, but I'm assuming the issue is roughly the same regardless of the type of DLL. The Shared COM Addin Wizard was used to get started, and then customization proceeded from there with satisfactory results...except for the invisible variables in the Locals window.

I'm new to writing & debugging a DLL like this; until now I've only done EXE files. I've researched MSDN, Google, and Stack Overflow, and here are the details that are asked about on other threads...

- Visual Studio 2008, .Net 3.0, and Access 2007
- Project Properties > Debug > External Program points to MSAccess.exe.
- Project configuration is set for Debug.
- Optimizations = off.
- Generate debug info = Full.
- The PDB file is present in the `\bin\` folder with the DLL.
- Breakpoints are working.
- Debug.Print messages are working.

I dug through the registry and found all references to the project, DLL, and its custom UserControl (required since the project creates a CustomTaskPane, and all path paths point to `\bin\` folder.

What am I doing wrong?

What am I doing right?

What can I improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after working on this for days in between other projects, I have an answer...of sorts. I think the solution and/or projects had become corrupt. I'll pass along what I can in the hope it may help others.

Yesterday I had a marathon session of "click everything", in the project settings and Options > Debugging, but nothign helped. At some point I stopped fiddling with the debug settings and continued working on the code until I was tired and went home.

This morning with a fresh mind I tried again, and discovered *the private class variables were now all visible*. And I don't know why. Also, there was a new problem: the Just-In-Time debugger prompt kept popping up, even thought it wasn't enabled in the settings:

[image]

Also, the play/stop/step toolbar buttons would become disabled when they shouldn't be, yet the menu selections for the same items functioned normally.

I double-checked all settings again. I played with everything and could NOT get the local class variables to become invisible again, and could not get the JIT dialog to go away.

So I...

- Made a copy of the solution folder.
- Cleaned the solution.
- Rebuilt the solution, including the Setup project.
- Uninstalled the Setup project from Windows via Solution Explorer.
- Cleaned the solution again.
- Deleted the SUO file.
- Deleted everything in \bin\ and \debug.
- Rebuilt the solution, including the Setup project.
- And still the problems persisted.

After the JIT prompt, I clicked Continue (F5), then closed MSAccess. Aafter execution stopped, some IDE panes (such as Explorer, Locals, etc) disappeared, and some flew around to random locations on the screen. It was then I decided something might be corrupt, and started making plans to uninstall/reinstall all of Visual Studio 2008 from scratch, and possibly even a new solution from scratch.

So before reinstalling, I tried creating a new solution from scratch, and found *everything worked perfectly, even with all settings as they were from the original solution*.

So in the original solution I...

- Exported the settings from Tools > Import and Export Settings.
- Reset all settings.
- Imported the settings I just saved.
- At the moment the import dialog closed, I received the error message: "An unexpected error has occurred".
- When restarting the VS IDE, I received a dialog that said "Visual Studio is configuring the environment for first time use". That didn't sound good.
- Tried importing the settings again, same error.
- Rebooted, tried importing again, same error.
- Closed the Solution file, tried importing the settings again without any solution open, and it worked....or seemed to.
- Then opened the Solution...and same problems were back.
- Exported the settings from the new Solution.
- Imported those settings into the original solution...and it's fixed..?
- *There was no import error, and the project started working correctly..!!*
- The local class variables were visible, and the JIT prompt was gone..!!

So...I guess something was bunged up in the Solution, one of the Projects, the IDE settings, or...something. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answering part of my own question. I think I fixed the error message "There is no source code available for the current location". In the project properties "Enable unmanaged code debugging" was enabled.

With that option disabled, I can now step through the code without error, even if it hits objects for which I have no code. The debugger is acting a little differently too, but I haven't yet pinned it down. I did read up on the differences between managed & unmanaged code, and debugging them in mixed combinations, but while I understand in principle, I don't yet understand in practice.

My local variables are still blank, though.

Comment: So this isn't actually an answer.  Do avoid asking multiple questions, the odds somebody knows the answer to all of them are low.

Comment: Yes, this is an answer to the error message, which I now know is only one issue. But I didn't know that when I made my OP, I simply described a group of symptoms which seemed to be related a possible single root cause. If no one is able to provide a complete answer to the entire post, mine may own answer may stand as the only one, even if incomplete.